# How to add extra key in created object in Django Rest Framework?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm new to Django

Currently I'm trying to add a simple extra key on my returned json in the serializer. Here's the `create()` override of my serializer:

```
    def create(self, validated_data):
        available_dates = validated_data.pop("available_dates")

        # Default expiry time is 3 days
        expiry = datetime.datetime.now() + datetime.timedelta(days=3)
        event = Events.objects.create(**validated_data, expiry=expiry)
        for selectedTime in available_dates:
            AvailableDates.objects.create(
                event=event,
                **selectedTime,
            )

        signer = Signer()
        signedObject = signer.sign_object(
            {"expiry": expiry.isoformat(), "id": event.id}
        )

        return {**event, "signed_url": signedObject}
```

As you can see, I don't want to only return event, but I want to add a signed url.

This gave me an error:
`'Events' object is not a mapping`

So then how do I add extra key? What do I return in the create function? Can I create `Response()` as the return of create function in DRF?

Comment: `create` is used to create a new model object in the database. You're rather looking to override [`to_representation`](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#overriding-serialization-and-deserialization-behavior)?!

Comment: Right.. but what if i only want to return the url after I create it? which part should i customise?

Comment: What does that mean?!

Comment: I meant i only want to add the `signed_url` key as a return on my `post` endpoint (when creating new row). @deceze. Hope that make sense

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `.create()` method of serializers need to return the instance that was created. After a successful create, it is used as the instance for the serializer when accessing `serializer.data` (Like how its used in a retrieve api)

---

As for adding a `signed_url`, you can add it in a field in your serializer, like:

```
class EventSerializer(ModelSerializer):
   # other fields ...
   signed_url = SerializerMethodField()

   class Meta:
       model = Event
       fields = [
           # other fields ...
           "signed_url",
       ]

   def create(self, validated_data):
        available_dates = validated_data.pop("available_dates")

        # Default expiry time is 3 days
        expiry = datetime.datetime.now() + datetime.timedelta(days=3)
        event = Events.objects.create(**validated_data, expiry=expiry)
        for selectedTime in available_dates:
            AvailableDates.objects.create(
                event=event,
                **selectedTime,
            )

        signer = Signer()
        signedObject = signer.sign_object(
            {"expiry": expiry.isoformat(), "id": event.id}
        )
        event.signedObject = signedObject

        return event
    def get_signed_url(self,obj):
         if not hasattr(obj, "signedObject"):
             return None
         # you can add other code here if you need to do something else with signedObject
         return obj.signedObject
```

There are other ways to do it. But the one above might do it based on the code provided.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I finally went with `to_representation`, however yours also works. thus i'll accept it as answer for others to see!